# Java controlling garbage collector

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I'm creating Android game with OpenGLES 2.0, and my game currently can render up to 55-60 frames per second, but I have a little problem with Garbage Collector, it slows down to 35 frames per second, and you can see a lag which damage user experience. It runs in totally random moments.

My question:
Is it possible to somehow control execution of Garbage Collector, for example can I delay GC for 0.5s or call GC before and be sure that GC wouldn't be called in next two second?  Or is there any way to reduce impact of GC on application execution?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can't stop the GC but you can force a call using `System.gc()`

try [these](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/12/coding-for-performance-and-avoiding-garbage-collection-in-android/) steps to avoid such problems with GC

Comment: But can I be sure that Java will not call GC after my force call (for example 2-3 s)?

Comment: we can't come to a conclusion on that, it may call GC immediately or even after 5sec, that is taken care by Java

Answer (score 2):

The garbage collector starts when it needs to free the memory from unused objects.

The best way to operate is reduce the number of new Objects reusing the old ones.

Read your code and every time you see the `new` keyword ask yourself *I really need a new Object here? Or I can reset an old unused Object?*

Try to read the tips in the developer android site http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

**Note:** a call to `System.gc()` is just a suggestion for the garbage collection system that automatically choose when to operate. From javadoc *"Calling this method **suggests** that the Java virtual machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects..."*

Comment: Does it mean that calling `System.gc()` immediately before important part of game is not good idea?

Comment: You are not sure that the garbage collector is invoked when you asked it. The best way to program a game is to elimate the necessity of garbage collection. The best is reuse objects, not create new ones. Invoking System.gc() can sometimes be a bad choice.

Comment: OK, but please check this scenario: 
For example, I have player and few enemies on screen(I don't know for example 5-10 enemies), and in one moment new enemies comes and join  others. Is it better to create this additional enemies before game starts(although they are not visible on screen, OpenGL must draw them every frame) or create object when I need to use that.
I know that is hard to say what is exactly better option, but I want to know what is better programming strategy?

Comment: The best is to create a List of unused enemies. When you need an enemy check if there is an object in the unused list. If yes pick it and populate with the values you need, if not create a new enemy. When you destroy an enemy or when you exit the screen put the unused enemies in the unused list

Comment: OK I know this, but I'm not sure is it profitable because OpenGL must draw used and unused object on screen. If you know what I mean, OpenGL will draw unused object outside of screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can't affect the GC in too many ways. It'll run when it has to (and when it decides it wants to).

You can try to minimize the amount it has to collect by reducing created objects, avoiding creating them or reusing old ones.